# not found file in server when build and uplaod project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a project in angular 9 and asp core 3 .

this is addres of site  :http://mag-testcpl.astromap.ir/

and it show me this error:

`http://mag-testcpl.astromap.ir/assets/vendors/global/toastr.css`

and this is in my html :

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Astronomy Mag | Admin panel</title>
<base href="/app">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/media/logos/favicon.png">
<link id="mainStyle" href="./assets/css/demo1/style.bundle.main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="ltrStyle" href="./assets/css/demo1/style.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="rtlStyle" href="./assets/css/demo1/style.bundle.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="toaster" href="./assets/vendors/global/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

</style>
```

when i enter this url in brwoser `http://mag-testcpl.astromap.ir/assets/vendors/global/toastr.css`
it not show me any things but when i enter this url in by this `http://mag-testcpl.astromap.ir/app/assets/vendors/global/toastr.css`

> add /app to url

it's worked and show me file .

i build the project with this command `ng build --prod --base-href /app`

**how  can i solve this problem ?????**

```
   "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/avastar",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.png",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/quill/assets/snow.styl",
          "./node_modules/quill/assets/core.styl",
          "./node_modules/quill/assets/bubble.styl"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/js/demo1/scripts.bundle.js"
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src",
            "src/stylings/",
            "src/stylings/base/",
            "src/stylings/kt-customs/"
          ]
        },
        "es5BrowserSupport": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "5mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "avastar:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "avastar:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "avastar:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please check with this <base href="/app">.

Comment: @KeyurGajjar yes it is . it /app

Comment: @KeyurGajjar that is mt index code

Comment: If you don't want the word app in your path, then try using  just  ng build --prod   at command line

Comment: @rickz i want use that

Comment: Please  show us what address what you want to type into browser ?

Comment: @rickz this aaddress http://mag-testcpl.astromap.ir/app/assets/vendors/global/toastr.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's first understand what is base href**

if you wan to use different base paths for router and static assets. Angular makes use of the base href to tell router how to compose navigation URLs. If your application exists at the root, then you can use / as the href value as shown.
`<base href="/">` ==> HTML

I wanted to use `/users` as my application base for router and `/public` as base for my assets.
`<base href="/users">` && `<link href="/public/styles.xxxx.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

So you must use this command 
`ng build -prod --base-href /users --deploy-url /public`

The answer is do you really need to append `app` to your route ? if no just use `ng build --prod`

Hope it helps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211177/discussion-on-answer-by-omar-hasan-not-found-file-in-server-when-build-and-uplao).